# How to Modify Emailfield in AbstractUser Model so that Email is Required

Tags: django

How to set emailfield to required when extending AbstractUser?

I was wondering how to override the AbstractUser's emailfield model to set it as required. Currently my form list the email field but does not set as required. By default shouldn't all models be required?

From the documentation it shows an example of how to set a field to required when creating a super user but I am not sure how to complete the task from the AbstractUser model without using AbstractBaseUser.

```python
model.py

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    authorization_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)


forms.py

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta (UserCreationForm):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'display_name', 'authorization_code')

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'bio')


admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'display_name', 'bio']
    list_display_links = ('username', 'display_name')

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'display_name', 'email', 'bio', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_staff', 'is_active')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'display_name', 'email', 'bio', 'password1', 'password2', 'is_staff', 'is_active')}
         ),
    )



admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

**Solution:**

```python
# It was as simple as updating my CustomUser model as shown:

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    authorization_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding `email` in **AbstractBaseUser**.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=False)       
    objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So it seems I should remove AbstractUser all together? Then subclass CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser) and add all my previous model fields along with the new email one? Do I need to manually add in all the previous default models fields that Django added by default in AbstractUser?